# How do I show specific data in Laravel Paginator?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I am using Laravel Pagination in my project. Currently, I can do `http://example.com/users?page=1`, which will provide limited access on showing specific users.

What I instead want is to have query parameters like `from` & `to` so that I can do `http://example.com/users?from=1&to=18`.

While inspecting the paginated output, I found this `meta` object, where it specifies from & to thingy:

```
"meta":{"current_page":1,"from":1,"last_page":1,"path":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users","per_page":10,"to":5,"total":5}"
```

How can I use this?

Comment: Use query() and pass the from and to as an array into it

Comment: You have to customize and create your own paginator